# React Native permanent AsyncStorage with Apollo3

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo

I am trying to built an app with permanent AsyncStorage. Following [this](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-cache-persist) docs I landed here.. The problem here is that it says client is not defined, because it's in a function. But the docs says, that the persistCache should be declared in a async function..

Can somebody help me to solve this problem in an elegant way?

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { persistCache, AsyncStorageWrapper } from "apollo3-cache-persist";

function App() {
    useEffect(() => {
        async function init() {
            const cache = new InMemoryCache();
            await persistCache({
                cache,
                storage: new AsyncStorageWrapper(AsyncStorage),
            });
            const client = new ApolloClient({
                link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
                cache: new InMemoryCache(),
            });
        }
        init();
    }, []);

    return (
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
            <AuthProvider>
                <Navigation />
            </AuthProvider>
        </ApolloProvider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `const [client, setClient] = useState(undefined);` missing ... as in docs ... and 'reuse' `cache`, don't create another, new instance later

Comment: I believe documentation is not up to date https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-cache-persist/issues/412